# Passing Null parameter value in ARM templete

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I want to pass a null value in a template, I have a template where in i am trying to pass a set of conditions to it for example say suppose if the cidr range does not exist skip the resource deployment, if the cidr range does exist proceed with deploying the resource.

```
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
    "condition": "[not(equals(parameters('environmentAbbreviation'), 'd01'))]",    
    "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
    "name": "[concat(variables('vnetResourceName'), '/',  variables('SubnetName'))]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('vnetResourceName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "addressPrefix": "[not(empty(parameters('SubnetAddressPrefix01')))]",
        "networkSecurityGroup": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('networkSecurityGroup1'))]"
        },
        "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Enabled",
        "privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies": "Enabled"
    }
},
```

I tried multiple ways to make the template work but throws a error stating parameter value as null,

for the above code i get error : Subnet is not formatted correctly. It should follow CIDR notation, for example 10.0.0.0/24. Even thou i am following a proper cidr range

Answer (score 0):

> To skip the resource deployment, if the CIDR range does exist:

*Use the following* `if condition` *in* `address prefix` *under the* `properties`.

***Modify*** `address prefix condition` ***as follows***:

```bash
"addressPrefix": "[if(not(empty(parameters('SubnetAddressPrefix01'),'yes'))), variables('SubnetAddressPrefix01'),  json('null'))]"
```

It will not throw a null parameter error, if you pass it like this.

You can refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-logical#not) for **"Logical functions of ARM templates".**

*After modifying it accordingly, I tried the replica of* `json` *in my environment and was able to deploy it successfully.*

[image]